# Solver for COVID-19 epidemic model with the Caputo fractional derivatives

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis

As it is known in biological system with memory it would be suitable to use fractional derivatives to describe evolution of the system. 
In a current version of Mathematica 12.1 there is no special solver for integrodifferential equations. 
Here we show solver with using Haar wavelets for dynamic system  (13) presented in a paper
M.A. Khan, A. Atangana, [Modeling the dynamics of novel coronavirus (2019-nCov) with fractional derivative](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.aej.2020.02.033), Alexandria Eng. J.
(2020)
[image: Figure 1]

with differential operator replaced with the Caputo definition for fractional derivative  as follows 
$$\frac {d f}{dt}\rightarrow \frac {1}{\Gamma (1-\rho)}\int_0^t{\frac{f'(x)dx}{(t-x)^{\rho}}}$$
The code below allows us to reproduce Figure 7 from the paper linked above. Let define functions

```
h[x_, k_, m_] := WaveletPsi[HaarWavelet[], m x - k];
h1[x_] := WaveletPhi[HaarWavelet[], x]
```

Let take $\rho =9/10$, and then we can calculate integrals

```
Integrate[h[t, k, m], {t, 0, x}, Assumptions -> {k >= 0, m > 0, x > 0}]

Integrate[h1[t], {t, 0, x}, Assumptions -> {x > 0}]

Integrate[h[x, k, m]/(t - x)^(9/10), {x, 0, t}, 
 Assumptions -> {t > 0, k >= 0, m > 0}]

Integrate[h1[x]/(t - x)^(9/10), {x, 0, t}, Assumptions -> {t > 0}]
```

With these integrals let define functions

```
p[x_, k_, m_] := Piecewise[{{(1 + k - m*x)/m, k >= 0 && 1/m + (2*k)/m - 2*x < 0 && 
      1/m + k/m - x >= 0 && m > 0}, {(-k + m*x)/m, k >= 0 && 1/m + (2*k)/m - 2*x >= 0 && 
      k/m - x < 0 && 1/m + k/m - x >= 0 && m > 0}}, 0]

p1[x_] := Piecewise[{{1, x > 1}}, x]

pc[t_, k_, m_] := Piecewise[{{10*t^(1/10), k == 0 && 1/m - 2*t >= 0 && m > 0 && t > 0 && 
      1/m + (2*k)/m - 2*t >= 0 && 1/m + k/m - t >= 0}, {(10*(-k + m*t)^(1/10))/m^(1/10), 
     k > 0 && 1/m + (2*k)/m - 2*t >= 0 && k/m - t < 0 && m > 0 && 1/m + k/m - t >= 0}, 
    {(10*((-k + m*t)^(1/10) - 2^(9/10)*(-1 - 2*k + 2*m*t)^(1/10)))/m^(1/10), 
     k > 0 && 1/m + (2*k)/m - 2*t < 0 && 1/m + k/m - t >= 0 && m > 0}, 
    {(10*((-1 - k + m*t)^(1/10) + (-k + m*t)^(1/10) - 2^(9/10)*(-1 - 2*k + 2*m*t)^(1/10)))/
      m^(1/10), k > 0 && 1/m + (2*k)/m - 2*t < 0 && 1/m + k/m - t < 0 && m > 0}, 
    {(5*(2*(m*t)^(1/10) - 2^(9/10)*(-1 + 2*m*t)^(1/10) - 2^(9/10)*(-1 - 2*k + 2*m*t)^(1/10)))/
      m^(1/10), k == 0 && 1/m - 2*t < 0 && 1/m + (2*k)/m - 2*t < 0 && 1/m + k/m - t >= 0 && m > 0}, 
    {(5*(2*(m*t)^(1/10) + 2*(-1 - k + m*t)^(1/10) - 2^(9/10)*(-1 + 2*m*t)^(1/10) - 
        2^(9/10)*(-1 - 2*k + 2*m*t)^(1/10)))/m^(1/10), k == 0 && 1/m - 2*t < 0 && 
      1/m + k/m - t < 0 && m > 0}}, 0]

pc1[t_] := Piecewise[{{-10*((-1 + t)^(1/10) - t^(1/10)), t >= 1}}, 10*t^(1/10)]
```

Now we have all functions to solve a problem

```
AbsoluteTiming[ J = 4; M = 2^J; dx = 1/(2*M); 
 Np0 = 8266000; 
  μp (*Natural mortality rate*)= 
  1/(76.79 365); Πp (*Birth rate*)= μp Np0 ; ηp \
(*Contact rate*)= 0.05; ψ (*Transmissibility multiple*) = 
  0.02; ηw (*Disease transmission coeﬃcient*)= 
  0.000001231; θp (*The proportion of asymptomatic \
infection*)= 0.1243; ωp (*Incubation period*)= 
  0.00047876;  ρp (*Incubation period*)= 
  0.005;  τp (*Removal or recovery rate of Ip*)= 
  0.09871;  τap (*Removal or recovery rate of Ap *)= 
  0.854302; ϱp (*Contribution of the virus to M by Ip*)= 
  0.000398; ϖp (*Contribution of the virus to M by Ap*) = 
  0.001; πp(*Removing rate of virus from M*) = 0.01;

 var1 = {Sp1, Ep1, Ip1, Ap1, Rp1, Mp1}; 
 var = {Sp, Ep, Ip, Ap, Rp, Mp}; aco = {aS, aE, aI, aA, aR, aM}; 
 aco1 = {aS1, aE1, aI1, aA1, aR1, aM1}; 
 aco0 = {aS0, aE0, aI0, aA0, aR0, aM0};
 A = 0; xl = Table[A + l dx, {l, 0, 2 M}]; 
 xcol = Table[(xl[[l - 1]] + xl[[l]])/2, {l, 2, 2 M + 1}];
 Sp1[x_] := 
  Sum[aS[i, j] pc[x, i, 2^j], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 
   aS1 pc1[x]; 
 Sp[x_] := 
  Sum[aS[i, j] p[x, i, 2^j], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 
   aS1 p1[x] + aS0; 
 Ep1[x_] := 
  Sum[aE[i, j] pc[x, i, 2^j], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 
   aE1 pc1[x]; 
 Ep[x_] := 
  Sum[aE[i, j] p[x, i, 2^j], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 
   aE1 p1[x] + aE0; 
 Ip1[x_] := 
  Sum[aI[i, j] pc[x, i, 2^j], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 
   aI1 pc1[x]; 
 Ip[x_] := 
  Sum[aI[i, j] p[x, i, 2^j], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 
   aI1 p1[x] + aI0; 
 Ap1[x_] := 
  Sum[aA[i, j] pc[x, i, 2^j], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 
   aA1 pc1[x]; 
 Ap[x_] := 
  Sum[aA[i, j] p[x, i, 2^j], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 
   aA1 p1[x] + aA0; 
 Rp1[x_] := 
  Sum[aR[i, j] pc[x, i, 2^j], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 
   aR1 pc1[x]; 
 Rp[x_] := 
  Sum[aR[i, j] p[x, i, 2^j], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 
   aR1 p1[x] + aR0; 
 Mp1[x_] := 
  Sum[aM[i, j] pc[x, i, 2^j], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 
   aM1 pc1[x]; 
 Mp[x_] := 
  Sum[aM[i, j] p[x, i, 2^j], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 
   aM1 p1[x] + aM0;

 varM = Join[aco0, aco1, 
   Flatten[Table[{aS[i, j], aE[i, j], aI[i, j], aA[i, j], aR[i, j], 
      aM[i, j]}, {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}]]];
 ρ = 9/10; tn = (1/120);
 eq1[t_] := -tn/Gamma[1 - ρ] Sp1[t] + Πp/
    Np0 - μp Sp[t] - ηp Sp[
     t] (Ip[t] + ψ Ap[t])/(Sp[t] + Ep[t] + Ip[t] + Ap[t] + 
       Rp[t]) - Np0 ηw Sp[t] Mp[t]; 
 eq2[t_] := -tn/Gamma[1 - ρ] Ep1[t] + ηp  Sp[
     t] (Ip[t] + ψ Ap[t])/(Sp[t] + Ep[t] + Ip[t] + Ap[t] + 
       Rp[t]) + 
   Np0 ηw Sp[t] Mp[t] - (1 - θp) ωp Ep[
     t] - θp ρp Ep[t] - μp Ep[t];
 eq3[t_] := -tn/Gamma[1 - ρ] Ip1[
     t] + (1 - θp) ωp Ep[t] - (τp + μp) Ip[t]; 
 eq4[t_] := -tn/Gamma[1 - ρ] Ap1[t] + θp ρp Ep[
     t] - (τap + μp) Ap[t]; 
 eq5[t_] := -tn/Gamma[1 - ρ] Rp1[t] + τp Ip[
     t] + τap Ap[t] - μp Rp[t]; 
 eq6[t_] := -tn/Gamma[1 - ρ] Mp1[t] + ϱp Ip[
     t] + ϖp Ap[t] - πp Mp[t];


 eq = Flatten[
   ParallelTable[{eq1[t] == 0, eq2[t] == 0, eq3[t] == 0, eq4[t] == 0, 
     eq5[t] == 0, eq6[t] == 0}, {t, xcol}]];
 Do[icv[i] = {Sp[0] == 8065518/Np0/8 i, Ep[0] == 200000/Np0, 
    Ip[0] == 282/Np0, Ap[0] == 200/Np0, Rp[0] == 0, 
    Mp[0] == 50000/Np0};
  eqM = Join[eq, icv[i]];
  solv[i] = 
   FindRoot[eqM, Table[{varM[[j]], .1}, {j, Length[varM]}], 
    MaxIterations -> 1000];
  lstSv[i] = 
   Table[{x 120 , Np0 Evaluate[Sp[x] /. solv[i]]}, {x, 0, 1, .01}]; 
  lstEv[i] = 
   Table[{x 120, Np0 Evaluate[Ep[x] /. solv[i]]}, {x, 0, 1, .01}]; 
  lstIv[i] = 
   Table[{x 120, Np0 Evaluate[Ip[x] /. solv[i]]}, {x, 0, 1, .01}]; 
  lstAv[i] = 
   Table[{x 120, Np0 Evaluate[Ap[x] /. solv[i]]}, {x, 0, 1, .01}]; 
  lstRv[i] = 
   Table[{x 120, Np0 Evaluate[Rp[x] /. solv[i]]}, {x, 0, 1, .01}]; 
  lstMv[i] = 
   Table[{x 120, Np0 Evaluate[Mp[x] /. solv[i]]}, {x, 0, 
     1, .01}];, {i, 1, 8}]]
```

Finally we visualize solution

```
{ListLinePlot[Table[lstSv[i], {i, 1, 8}], Frame -> True, 
     FrameLabel -> {"t, days", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(S\), \(p\)]\)"}, 
  PlotRange -> All], 
   ListLinePlot[Table[lstEv[i], {i, 1, 8}], Frame -> True, 
     FrameLabel -> {"t, days", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(E\), \(p\)]\)"}, 
  PlotRange -> All], 
   ListLinePlot[Table[lstIv[i], {i, 1, 8}], Frame -> True, 
     FrameLabel -> {"t, days", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(I\), \(p\)]\)"}, 
  PlotRange -> All], 
   ListLinePlot[Table[lstAv[i], {i, 1, 8}], Frame -> True, 
     FrameLabel -> {"t, days", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(A\), \(p\)]\)"}, 
  PlotRange -> All], 
   ListLinePlot[Table[lstRv[i], {i, 1, 8}], Frame -> True, 
     FrameLabel -> {"t, days", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(R\), \(p\)]\)"}, 
  PlotRange -> All], 
   ListLinePlot[Table[lstMv[i], {i, 1, 8}], Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"t, days", "M"}, 
     PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Automatic]}
```

[image: Figure 2]

The question is about how to add $\rho$ in this code as parameter?

Update 1. The straight forward solution of this problem is simply to include $\rho$ in the `pc, pc1`functions definitions as follows (here $\rho$ is replaced by `q`) :

```
pc[t_, k_, m_, q_] := 
 Piecewise[{{-(t^(1 - q)/(-1 + q)), k == 0 && 1/m - 2*t >= 0 && 
          m > 0 && t > 0 && 1/m - t >= 0}, 
      {-((m^(-1 + q)*(1/(-k + m*t))^(-1 + q))/(-1 + q)), 
        k > 0 && 1/m + (2*k)/m - 2*t > 0 && k/m - t < 0 && m > 0 && 
          1/m + k/m - t > 0}, 
      {(-t^q + 2*m*t^(1 + q) - m*t*(-(1/(2*m)) + t)^q)/
          (t^q*(-(1/(2*m)) + t)^q*(m*(-1 + q))), 
        k == 0 && m > 0 && 1/m - 2*t < 0 && 1/m - t >= 0}, 
      {(1/(-1 + q))*((2^(-1 + q)*m^(-1 + 2*q)*(-(-(k/m) + t)^q - 
                   2*k*(-(k/m) + t)^q + 2*m*t*(-(k/m) + t)^q + 
                   2*k*(-((1/2 + k)/m) + t)^q - 
           2*m*t*(-((1/2 + k)/m) + t)^
                       q))/((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(k - m*t))^q), 
        k > 0 && 1/m + (2*k)/m - 2*t == 0 && m > 0 && 
          1/m + k/m - t > 0}, 
      {-((1/(-1 + q))*((2^(-1 + q)*m^(-1 + 2*q)*
                   (-2*(-((1/2 + k)/m) + t)^
               q*((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(k - m*t))^
                          q - 2*k*(-((1/2 + k)/m) + t)^q*
                        ((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(k - m*t))^q + 
                      2*m*t*(-((1/2 + k)/m) + t)^q*((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*
                             (k - m*t))^q + (-((1 + k)/m) + t)^q*
                        ((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(k - m*t))^q + 

             2*k*(-((1 + k)/m) + t)^q*((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(k - m*t))^
                          q - 2*m*t*(-((1 + k)/m) + t)^q*
                        ((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(k - m*t))^
               q + (-(k/m) + t)^q*
                        ((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(1 + k - m*t))^q + 

             2*k*(-(k/m) + t)^q*((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(1 + k - m*t))^q - 

             2*m*t*(-(k/m) + t)^q*((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(1 + k - m*t))^
                          q - 2*k*(-((1/2 + k)/m) + t)^q*
                        ((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(1 + k - m*t))^q + 
                      2*m*t*(-((1/2 + k)/m) + t)^q*((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*
                             (1 + k - m*t))^
               q))/(((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(k - m*t))^q*
                   ((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(1 + k - m*t))^q))), 
        k > 0 && m > 0 && 1/m + (2*k)/m - 2*t <= 0 && 
          1/m + k/m - t <= 0}, 
      {-((1/(2*m*(-1 + q)))*((2^q*m^(2*q)*t^q*(-(1/m) + t)^q*
                     (-(1/(2*m)) + t)^q - 
           2^(1 + q)*m^(1 + 2*q)*t^(1 + q)*
                     (-(1/m) + t)^q*(-(1/(2*m)) + t)^q - 
           2^(1 + q)*m^(2*q)*
                     t^q*(-(1/(2*m)) + t)^(2*q) + 
           2^(1 + q)*m^(1 + 2*q)*
                     t^(1 + q)*(-(1/(2*m)) + t)^(2*q) + 
                   t^q*((-1 + m*t)*(-1 + 2*m*t))^q - 2*m*t^(1 + q)*
                     ((-1 + m*t)*(-1 + 2*m*t))^q + 
           2*m*t*(-(1/(2*m)) + t)^q*
                     ((-1 + m*t)*(-1 + 2*m*t))^q)/(t^
            q*(-(1/(2*m)) + t)^q*
                   ((-1 + m*t)*(-1 + 2*m*t))^q))), 
        k == 0 && 1/m - 2*t < 0 && 1/m - t < 0 && m > 0}, 
      {(1/(-1 + q))*((2^(-1 + q)*m^(-1 + q)*((-m^q)*(-(k/m) + t)^q - 
                   2*k*m^q*(-(k/m) + t)^q + 
           2*m^(1 + q)*t*(-(k/m) + t)^q + 
                   2*k*m^q*(-((1/2 + k)/m) + t)^q - 2*m^(1 + q)*t*
                     (-((1/2 + k)/m) + t)^
             q - ((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(k - m*t))^q*
                     (1/(-1 - 2*k + 2*m*t))^q - 
                   2*k*((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(k - m*t))^q*
                     (1/(-1 - 2*k + 2*m*t))^q + 
                   2*m*t*((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(k - m*t))^q*
                     (1/(-1 - 2*k + 2*m*t))^q))/((1 + 2*k - 
            2*m*t)*(k - m*t))^
               q), 1/m + (2*k)/m - 2*t < 0 && k > 0 && m > 0 && 
          1/m + k/m - t > 0}}, 0]

pc1[t_, q_] := Piecewise[{{-(t^(1 - q)/(-1 + q)), t <= 1}}, 
    -(((-1 + t)^q*t + t^q - t^(1 + q))/((-1 + t)^q*t^q*(-1 + q)))]
```

With these functions we can calculate Figure 6 from the paper above with the next piece of code

```
AbsoluteTiming[J = 4; M = 2^J; dx = 1/(2*M); 
 Np0 = 8266000; 
  \[Mu]p (*Natural mortality rate*)= 
  1/(76.79 365); \[CapitalPi]p (*Birth rate*)= \[Mu]p Np0 ; \[Eta]p \
(*Contact rate*)= 0.05; \[Psi] (*Transmissibility multiple*) = 
  0.02; \[Eta]w (*Disease transmission coeﬃcient*)= 
  0.000001231; \[Theta]p (*The proportion of asymptomatic \
infection*)= 0.1243; \[Omega]p (*Incubation period*)= 
  0.00047876;  \[Rho]p (*Incubation period*)= 
  0.005;  \[Tau]p (*Removal or recovery rate of Ip*)= 
  0.09871;  \[Tau]ap (*Removal or recovery rate of Ap *)= 
  0.854302; \[CurlyRho]p (*Contribution of the virus to M by Ip*)= 
  0.000398; \[CurlyPi]p (*Contribution of the virus to M by Ap*) = 
  0.001; \[Pi]p(*Removing rate of virus from M*) = 0.01;

 var1 = {Sp1, Ep1, Ip1, Ap1, Rp1, Mp1}; 
 var = {Sp, Ep, Ip, Ap, Rp, Mp}; aco = {aS, aE, aI, aA, aR, aM}; 
 aco1 = {aS1, aE1, aI1, aA1, aR1, aM1}; 
 aco0 = {aS0, aE0, aI0, aA0, aR0, aM0};
 A = 0; xl = Table[A + l dx, {l, 0, 2 M}]; 
 xcol = Table[(xl[[l - 1]] + xl[[l]])/2, {l, 2, 2 M + 1}];
 Sp1[x_, q_] := 
  Sum[aS[i, j] pc[x, i, 2^j, q], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 
   aS1 pc1[x, q]; 
 Sp[x_] := 
  Sum[aS[i, j] p[x, i, 2^j], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 
   aS1 p1[x] + aS0; 
 Ep1[x_, q_] := 
  Sum[aE[i, j] pc[x, i, 2^j, q], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 
   aE1 pc1[x, q]; 
 Ep[x_] := 
  Sum[aE[i, j] p[x, i, 2^j], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 
   aE1 p1[x] + aE0; 
 Ip1[x_, q_] := 
  Sum[aI[i, j] pc[x, i, 2^j, q], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 
   aI1 pc1[x, q]; 
 Ip[x_] := 
  Sum[aI[i, j] p[x, i, 2^j], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 
   aI1 p1[x] + aI0; 
 Ap1[x_, q_] := 
  Sum[aA[i, j] pc[x, i, 2^j, q], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 
   aA1 pc1[x, q]; 
 Ap[x_] := 
  Sum[aA[i, j] p[x, i, 2^j], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 
   aA1 p1[x] + aA0; 
 Rp1[x_, q_] := 
  Sum[aR[i, j] pc[x, i, 2^j, q], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 
   aR1 pc1[x, q]; 
 Rp[x_] := 
  Sum[aR[i, j] p[x, i, 2^j], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 
   aR1 p1[x] + aR0; 
 Mp1[x_, q_] := 
  Sum[aM[i, j] pc[x, i, 2^j, q], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 
   aM1 pc1[x, q]; 
 Mp[x_] := 
  Sum[aM[i, j] p[x, i, 2^j], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 
   aM1 p1[x] + aM0;

 varM = Join[aco0, aco1, 
   Flatten[Table[{aS[i, j], aE[i, j], aI[i, j], aA[i, j], aR[i, j], 
      aM[i, j]}, {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}]]];
 tn[q_] := (1/120)^q;
 eq1[t_, q_] := -tn[q]/Gamma[1 - q] Sp1[t, q] + \[CapitalPi]p/
    Np0 - \[Mu]p Sp[t] - \[Eta]p Sp[
     t] (Ip[t] + \[Psi] Ap[t])/(Sp[t] + Ep[t] + Ip[t] + Ap[t] + 
       Rp[t]) - Np0 \[Eta]w Sp[t] Mp[t]; 
 eq2[t_, q_] := -tn[q]/Gamma[1 - q] Ep1[t, q] + \[Eta]p  Sp[
     t] (Ip[t] + \[Psi] Ap[t])/(Sp[t] + Ep[t] + Ip[t] + Ap[t] + 
       Rp[t]) + 
   Np0 \[Eta]w Sp[t] Mp[t] - (1 - \[Theta]p) \[Omega]p Ep[
     t] - \[Theta]p \[Rho]p Ep[t] - \[Mu]p Ep[t];
 eq3[t_, q_] := -tn[q]/Gamma[1 - q] Ip1[t, 
     q] + (1 - \[Theta]p) \[Omega]p Ep[t] - (\[Tau]p + \[Mu]p) Ip[t]; 
 eq4[t_, q_] := -tn[q]/Gamma[1 - q] Ap1[t, q] + \[Theta]p \[Rho]p Ep[
     t] - (\[Tau]ap + \[Mu]p) Ap[t]; 
 eq5[t_, q_] := -tn[q]/Gamma[1 - q] Rp1[t, q] + \[Tau]p Ip[
     t] + \[Tau]ap Ap[t] - \[Mu]p Rp[t]; 
 eq6[t_, q_] := -tn[q]/Gamma[1 - q] Mp1[t, q] + \[CurlyRho]p Ip[
     t] + \[CurlyPi]p Ap[t] - \[Pi]p Mp[t];


 eq[q_] := 
  Flatten[ParallelTable[{eq1[t, q] == 0, eq2[t, q] == 0, 
     eq3[t, q] == 0, eq4[t, q] == 0, eq5[t, q] == 0, 
     eq6[t, q] == 0}, {t, xcol}]];
 Do[icv[i] = {Sp[0] == 8065518/Np0, Ep[0] == 200000/Np0, 
    Ip[0] == 282/Np0, Ap[0] == 200/Np0, Rp[0] == 0, 
    Mp[0] == 50000/Np0};
  eqM[i] = Join[eq[i], icv[i]];
  solv[i] = 
   FindRoot[eqM[i], Table[{varM[[j]], .1}, {j, Length[varM]}], 
    MaxIterations -> 1000];
  lstSv[i] = 
   Table[{x 120 , Np0 Evaluate[Sp[x] /. solv[i]]}, {x, 0, 1, .01}]; 
  lstEv[i] = 
   Table[{x 120, Np0 Evaluate[Ep[x] /. solv[i]]}, {x, 0, 1, .01}]; 
  lstIv[i] = 
   Table[{x 120, Np0 Evaluate[Ip[x] /. solv[i]]}, {x, 0, 1, .01}]; 
  lstAv[i] = 
   Table[{x 120, Np0 Evaluate[Ap[x] /. solv[i]]}, {x, 0, 1, .01}]; 
  lstRv[i] = 
   Table[{x 120, Np0 Evaluate[Rp[x] /. solv[i]]}, {x, 0, 1, .01}]; 
  lstMv[i] = 
   Table[{x 120, Np0 Evaluate[Mp[x] /. solv[i]]}, {x, 0, 
     1, .01}];, {i, {99/100, 9/10, 8/10, 7/10, 6/10}}];]
```

We can check that it is run 4-5 times longer than code with a fixed $\rho$. Visualization:

```
{ListLinePlot[Table[lstSv[i], {i, {99/100, 9/10, 8/10, 7/10, 6/10}}], 
  Frame -> True, 
     FrameLabel -> {"t, days", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(S\), \(p\)]\)"}, 
  PlotRange -> All], 
   ListLinePlot[
  Table[lstEv[i], {i, {99/100, 9/10, 8/10, 7/10, 6/10}}], 
  Frame -> True, 
     FrameLabel -> {"t, days", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(E\), \(p\)]\)"}, 
  PlotRange -> All], 
   ListLinePlot[
  Table[lstIv[i], {i, {99/100, 9/10, 8/10, 7/10, 6/10}}], 
  Frame -> True, 
     FrameLabel -> {"t, days", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(I\), \(p\)]\)"}, 
  PlotRange -> All], 
   ListLinePlot[
  Table[lstAv[i], {i, {99/100, 9/10, 8/10, 7/10, 6/10}}], 
  Frame -> True, 
     FrameLabel -> {"t, days", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(A\), \(p\)]\)"}, 
  PlotRange -> All], 
   ListLinePlot[
  Table[lstRv[i], {i, {99/100, 9/10, 8/10, 7/10, 6/10}}], 
  Frame -> True, 
     FrameLabel -> {"t, days", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(R\), \(p\)]\)"}, 
  PlotRange -> All], 
   ListLinePlot[
  Table[lstMv[i], {i, {99/100, 9/10, 8/10, 7/10, 6/10}}], 
  Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"t, days", "M"}, 
     PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Automatic]}
```

[image: Figure 2]

Update 2. We can reduce time by 3-4 times  simply replace where it is possible function definition `f[x_,...]:=...` with `f=Compile[{{x,_Real},{...}},...]`. So in the last code we have to replace first part as follows

```
h = Compile[{{x, _Real}, {k, _Integer}, {m, _Integer}}, 
   WaveletPsi[HaarWavelet[], m x - k]];

p = Compile[{{x, _Real}, {k, _Integer}, {m, _Integer}}, 
   Piecewise[{{(1 + k - m*x)/m, k >= 0 && 1/m + (2*k)/m - 2*x < 0 && 
             1/m + k/m - x >= 0 && m > 0}, {(-k + m*x)/m, 
      k >= 0 && 1/m + (2*k)/m - 2*x >= 0 && 
             k/m - x < 0 && 1/m + k/m - x >= 0 && m > 0}}, 0]];
h1 = Compile[{{x, _Real}}, WaveletPhi[HaarWavelet[], x]];

p1 = Compile[{{x, _Real}}, Piecewise[{{1, x > 1}}, x]];

pc = Compile[{{t, _Real}, {k, _Integer}, {m, _Integer}, {q, _Real}}, 
   Piecewise[{{-(t^(1 - q)/(-1 + q)), k == 0 && 1/m - 2*t >= 0 && 
            m > 0 && t > 0 && 1/m - t >= 0}, 
        {-((m^(-1 + q)*(1/(-k + m*t))^(-1 + q))/(-1 + q)), 
          k > 0 && 1/m + (2*k)/m - 2*t > 0 && k/m - t < 0 && m > 0 && 
            1/m + k/m - t > 0}, 
        {(-t^q + 2*m*t^(1 + q) - m*t*(-(1/(2*m)) + t)^q)/
            (t^q*(-(1/(2*m)) + t)^q*(m*(-1 + q))), 
          k == 0 && m > 0 && 1/m - 2*t < 0 && 1/m - t >= 0}, 
        {(1/(-1 + q))*((2^(-1 + q)*m^(-1 + 2*q)*(-(-(k/m) + t)^q - 
                     2*k*(-(k/m) + t)^q + 2*m*t*(-(k/m) + t)^q + 
                     2*k*(-((1/2 + k)/m) + t)^q - 
             2*m*t*(-((1/2 + k)/m) + t)^
                         q))/((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(k - m*t))^q), 
          k > 0 && 1/m + (2*k)/m - 2*t == 0 && m > 0 && 
            1/m + k/m - t > 0}, 
        {-((1/(-1 + q))*((2^(-1 + q)*m^(-1 + 2*q)*
                     (-2*(-((1/2 + k)/m) + t)^
                 q*((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(k - m*t))^
                            q - 2*k*(-((1/2 + k)/m) + t)^q*
                          ((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(k - m*t))^q + 

               2*m*t*(-((1/2 + k)/m) + t)^q*((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*
                               (k - m*t))^q + (-((1 + k)/m) + t)^q*
                          ((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(k - m*t))^q + 

               2*k*(-((1 + k)/m) + t)^q*((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(k - m*t))^
                            q - 2*m*t*(-((1 + k)/m) + t)^q*
                          ((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(k - m*t))^
                 q + (-(k/m) + t)^q*
                          ((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(1 + k - m*t))^q + 

               2*k*(-(k/m) + t)^q*((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(1 + k - m*t))^
                 q - 

               2*m*t*(-(k/m) + t)^q*((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(1 + k - m*t))^
                            q - 2*k*(-((1/2 + k)/m) + t)^q*
                          ((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(1 + k - m*t))^q + 

               2*m*t*(-((1/2 + k)/m) + t)^q*((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*
                               (1 + k - m*t))^
                 q))/(((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(k - m*t))^q*
                     ((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(1 + k - m*t))^q))), 
          k > 0 && m > 0 && 1/m + (2*k)/m - 2*t <= 0 && 
            1/m + k/m - t <= 0}, 
        {-((1/(2*m*(-1 + q)))*((2^q*m^(2*q)*t^q*(-(1/m) + t)^q*
                       (-(1/(2*m)) + t)^q - 
             2^(1 + q)*m^(1 + 2*q)*t^(1 + q)*
                       (-(1/m) + t)^q*(-(1/(2*m)) + t)^q - 
             2^(1 + q)*m^(2*q)*
                       t^q*(-(1/(2*m)) + t)^(2*q) + 
             2^(1 + q)*m^(1 + 2*q)*
                       t^(1 + q)*(-(1/(2*m)) + t)^(2*q) + 
                     t^q*((-1 + m*t)*(-1 + 2*m*t))^q - 2*m*t^(1 + q)*
                       ((-1 + m*t)*(-1 + 2*m*t))^q + 
             2*m*t*(-(1/(2*m)) + t)^q*
                       ((-1 + m*t)*(-1 + 2*m*t))^q)/(t^
              q*(-(1/(2*m)) + t)^q*
                     ((-1 + m*t)*(-1 + 2*m*t))^q))), 
          k == 0 && 1/m - 2*t < 0 && 1/m - t < 0 && m > 0}, 
        {(1/(-1 + q))*((2^(-1 + q)*m^(-1 + q)*((-m^q)*(-(k/m) + t)^q - 
                     2*k*m^q*(-(k/m) + t)^q + 
             2*m^(1 + q)*t*(-(k/m) + t)^q + 
                     2*k*m^q*(-((1/2 + k)/m) + t)^q - 2*m^(1 + q)*t*
                       (-((1/2 + k)/m) + t)^
               q - ((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(k - m*t))^q*
                       (1/(-1 - 2*k + 2*m*t))^q - 
                     2*k*((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(k - m*t))^q*
                       (1/(-1 - 2*k + 2*m*t))^q + 
                     2*m*t*((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(k - m*t))^q*
                       (1/(-1 - 2*k + 2*m*t))^q))/((1 + 2*k - 
              2*m*t)*(k - m*t))^
                 q), 1/m + (2*k)/m - 2*t < 0 && k > 0 && m > 0 && 
            1/m + k/m - t > 0}}, 0]];

pc1 = Compile[{{t, _Real}, {q, _Real}}, 
  Piecewise[{{-(t^(1 - q)/(-1 + q)), t <= 1}}, 
     -(((-1 + t)^q*t + t^q - t^(1 + q))/((-1 + t)^q*
        t^q*(-1 + q)))]]; tn = Compile[{{q, _Real}}, (1/120)^q];
```

Comment: "it would be suitable to use fractional derivatives to describe evolution of the system" - just out of curiosity, do you have a good reference that demonstrates this?

Comment: @Szabolcs This code  is quite good for particular $\rho$ (it takes few second to calculate solution). To make it faster  I have introduced functions like `pc[t,k,m], pc1[t,k,m]` calculated with a given $\rho$. But when I try to use it in general  form as  a functions of $\rho$, it takes hundred times longer.

Comment: @ChrisK I have few papers about application of fractional derivatives to biological systems including this one https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.01820

Comment: Note that there is now `ResourceFunction["FractionalIntegrate"]` in the Wolfram Function Repository.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau How can we use this function for our problem?

Comment: @Daniel, I think Alex would use `ResourceFunction["FractionalD"]` instead for this, since he wants the Caputo derivative.

Comment: @AlexTrounev could you please consider presenting and announcing your work on Wolfram Community?

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov Thank you, I will do in a short time.

Comment: Ok, this code also posted on https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1976589

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`WaveletPsi` is not compilable, so I changed some of your compile definitions.
Changing the parallel evaluation a little bit your code runs now in about a second on a simple 4-core machine.
Using the experimental `FunctionCompile` does not help at all, since both the `Piecewise` and the `HaarWavelet` function generate compile errors. Looks like those functions are not among the "approximately 2000 functions which cover 31 functionality areas" [[Compiler paper]](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/3368826.3377913).

```
h = Function[{x, k, m}, WaveletPsi[HaarWavelet[], m x - k]]; 

p = Compile[{{x, _Real}, {k, _Integer}, {m, _Integer}}, 
   Piecewise[{{(1 + k - m*x)/m, 
      k >= 0 && 1/m + (2*k)/m - 2*x < 0 && 1/m + k/m - x >= 0 && 
       m > 0}, {(-k + m*x)/m, 
      k >= 0 && 1/m + (2*k)/m - 2*x >= 0 && k/m - x < 0 && 
       1/m + k/m - x >= 0 && m > 0}}, 0]];

h1 = Function[{x}, WaveletPhi[HaarWavelet[], x]];

p1 = Function[x, Piecewise[{{1, x > 1}}, x]];

pc = Compile[{{t, _Real}, {k, _Integer}, {m, _Integer}, {q, _Real}}, 
   Piecewise[{{-(t^(1 - q)/(-1 + q)), 
      k == 0 && 1/m - 2*t >= 0 && m > 0 && t > 0 && 
       1/m - t >= 
        0}, {-((m^(-1 + q)*(1/(-k + m*t))^(-1 + q))/(-1 + q)), 
      k > 0 && 1/m + (2*k)/m - 2*t > 0 && k/m - t < 0 && m > 0 && 
       1/m + k/m - t > 
        0}, {(-t^q + 2*m*t^(1 + q) - 
         m*t*(-(1/(2*m)) + t)^q)/(t^q*(-(1/(2*m)) + t)^
          q*(m*(-1 + q))), 
      k == 0 && m > 0 && 1/m - 2*t < 0 && 
       1/m - t >= 
        0}, {(1/(-1 + q))*((2^(-1 + q)*
           m^(-1 + 2*q)*(-(-(k/m) + t)^q - 2*k*(-(k/m) + t)^q + 
             2*m*t*(-(k/m) + t)^q + 2*k*(-((1/2 + k)/m) + t)^q - 
             2*m*t*(-((1/2 + k)/m) + t)^q))/((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(k - 
              m*t))^q), 
      k > 0 && 1/m + (2*k)/m - 2*t == 0 && m > 0 && 
       1/m + k/m - t > 
        0}, {-((1/(-1 + q))*((2^(-1 + q)*
             m^(-1 + 
                2*q)*(-2*(-((1/2 + k)/m) + t)^
                 q*((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(k - m*t))^q - 
               2*k*(-((1/2 + k)/m) + t)^
                 q*((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(k - m*t))^q + 
               2*m*t*(-((1/2 + k)/m) + t)^
                 q*((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(k - m*t))^
                 q + (-((1 + k)/m) + t)^
                 q*((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(k - m*t))^q + 
               2*k*(-((1 + k)/m) + t)^q*((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(k - m*t))^
                 q - 2*m*
                t*(-((1 + k)/m) + t)^q*((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(k - m*t))^
                 q + (-(k/m) + t)^q*((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(1 + k - m*t))^
                 q + 2*k*(-(k/m) + t)^
                 q*((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(1 + k - m*t))^q - 
               2*m*t*(-(k/m) + t)^q*((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(1 + k - m*t))^
                 q - 2*k*(-((1/2 + k)/m) + t)^
                 q*((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(1 + k - m*t))^q + 
               2*m*t*(-((1/2 + k)/m) + t)^
                 q*((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(1 + k - m*t))^
                 q))/(((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(k - m*t))^
              q*((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(1 + k - m*t))^q))), 
      k > 0 && m > 0 && 1/m + (2*k)/m - 2*t <= 0 && 
       1/m + k/m - t <= 
        0}, {-((1/(2*
             m*(-1 + q)))*((2^q*m^(2*q)*
              t^q*(-(1/m) + t)^q*(-(1/(2*m)) + t)^q - 
             2^(1 + q)*m^(1 + 2*q)*
              t^(1 + q)*(-(1/m) + t)^q*(-(1/(2*m)) + t)^q - 
             2^(1 + q)*m^(2*q)*t^q*(-(1/(2*m)) + t)^(2*q) + 
             2^(1 + q)*m^(1 + 2*q)*t^(1 + q)*(-(1/(2*m)) + t)^(2*q) + 
             t^q*((-1 + m*t)*(-1 + 2*m*t))^q - 
             2*m*t^(1 + q)*((-1 + m*t)*(-1 + 2*m*t))^q + 
             2*m*t*(-(1/(2*m)) + t)^q*((-1 + m*t)*(-1 + 2*m*t))^q)/(t^
              q*(-(1/(2*m)) + t)^q*((-1 + m*t)*(-1 + 2*m*t))^q))), 
      k == 0 && 1/m - 2*t < 0 && 1/m - t < 0 && 
       m > 0}, {(1/(-1 + q))*((2^(-1 + q)*
           m^(-1 + q)*((-m^q)*(-(k/m) + t)^q - 
             2*k*m^q*(-(k/m) + t)^q + 2*m^(1 + q)*t*(-(k/m) + t)^q + 
             2*k*m^q*(-((1/2 + k)/m) + t)^q - 
             2*m^(1 + q)*
              t*(-((1/2 + k)/m) + t)^
               q - ((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(k - m*t))^
               q*(1/(-1 - 2*k + 2*m*t))^q - 
             2*k*((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(k - m*t))^
               q*(1/(-1 - 2*k + 2*m*t))^q + 
             2*m*t*((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(k - m*t))^
               q*(1/(-1 - 2*k + 2*m*t))^q))/((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(k - 
              m*t))^q), 
      1/m + (2*k)/m - 2*t < 0 && k > 0 && m > 0 && 
       1/m + k/m - t > 0}}, 0]];

pc1 = Compile[{{t, _Real}, {q, _Real}}, 
   Piecewise[{{-(t^(1 - q)/(-1 + q)), 
      t <= 1}}, -(((-1 + t)^q*t + t^q - t^(1 + q))/((-1 + t)^q*
         t^q*(-1 + q)))]];

tn = Function[{q}, (1/120)^q];


(*Now we have all functions to solve a problem with the given \
parameres*)

LaunchKernels[] (* Launch parallel kernels before doing \
AbsoluteTiming *)

AbsoluteTiming[
 J = 4; M = 2^J; dx = 1/(2*M);
 Np0 = 8266000;
 \[Mu]p (*Natural mortality rate*)= 
  1/(76.79 365); \[CapitalPi]p (*Birth rate*)= \[Mu]p Np0; \[Eta]p \
(*Contact rate*)= 0.05; \[Psi] (*Transmissibility multiple*)= 
  0.02; \[Eta]w (*Disease transmission coeﬃcient*)= 
  0.000001231; \[Theta]p (*The proportion of asymptomatic infection*)=
   0.1243; \[Omega]p (*Incubation period*)= 
  0.00047876; \[Rho]p (*Incubation period*)= 
  0.005; \[Tau]p (*Removal or recovery rate of Ip*)= 
  0.09871; \[Tau]ap (*Removal or recovery rate of Ap*)= 
  0.854302; \[CurlyRho]p (*Contribution of the virus to M by Ip*)= 
  0.000398; \[CurlyPi]p (*Contribution of the virus to M by Ap*)= 
  0.001; \[Pi]p(*Removing rate of virus from M*)= 0.01;
 var1 = {Sp1, Ep1, Ip1, Ap1, Rp1, Mp1};
 var = {Sp, Ep, Ip, Ap, Rp, Mp}; aco = {aS, aE, aI, aA, aR, aM};
 aco1 = {aS1, aE1, aI1, aA1, aR1, aM1};
 aco0 = {aS0, aE0, aI0, aA0, aR0, aM0};
 A = 0; xl = Table[A + l dx, {l, 0, 2 M}];
 xcol = Table[(xl[[l - 1]] + xl[[l]])/2, {l, 2, 2 M + 1}];
 Sp1[x_, q_] := 
  Sum[aS[i, j] pc[x, i, 2^j, q], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 
   aS1 pc1[x, q];
 Sp[x_] := 
  Sum[aS[i, j] p[x, i, 2^j], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 
   aS1 p1[x] + aS0;
 Ep1[x_, q_] := 
  Sum[aE[i, j] pc[x, i, 2^j, q], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 
   aE1 pc1[x, q];
 Ep[x_] := 
  Sum[aE[i, j] p[x, i, 2^j], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 
   aE1 p1[x] + aE0;
 Ip1[x_, q_] := 
  Sum[aI[i, j] pc[x, i, 2^j, q], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 
   aI1 pc1[x, q];
 Ip[x_] := 
  Sum[aI[i, j] p[x, i, 2^j], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 
   aI1 p1[x] + aI0;
 Ap1[x_, q_] := 
  Sum[aA[i, j] pc[x, i, 2^j, q], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 
   aA1 pc1[x, q];
 Ap[x_] := 
  Sum[aA[i, j] p[x, i, 2^j], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 
   aA1 p1[x] + aA0;
 Rp1[x_, q_] := 
  Sum[aR[i, j] pc[x, i, 2^j, q], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 
   aR1 pc1[x, q];
 Rp[x_] := 
  Sum[aR[i, j] p[x, i, 2^j], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 
   aR1 p1[x] + aR0;
 Mp1[x_, q_] := 
  Sum[aM[i, j] pc[x, i, 2^j, q], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 
   aM1 pc1[x, q];
 Mp[x_] := 
  Sum[aM[i, j] p[x, i, 2^j], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 
   aM1 p1[x] + aM0;
 varM = Join[aco0, aco1, 
   Flatten[Table[{aS[i, j], aE[i, j], aI[i, j], aA[i, j], aR[i, j], 
      aM[i, j]}, {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}]]];

 eq1[t_, q_] := -tn[q]/Gamma[1 - q] Sp1[t, q] + \[CapitalPi]p/
    Np0 - \[Mu]p Sp[t] - \[Eta]p Sp[
     t] (Ip[t] + \[Psi] Ap[t])/(Sp[t] + Ep[t] + Ip[t] + Ap[t] + 
       Rp[t]) - Np0 \[Eta]w Sp[t] Mp[t];
 eq2[t_, q_] := -tn[q]/Gamma[1 - q] Ep1[t, q] + \[Eta]p Sp[
     t] (Ip[t] + \[Psi] Ap[t])/(Sp[t] + Ep[t] + Ip[t] + Ap[t] + 
       Rp[t]) + 
   Np0 \[Eta]w Sp[t] Mp[t] - (1 - \[Theta]p) \[Omega]p Ep[
     t] - \[Theta]p \[Rho]p Ep[t] - \[Mu]p Ep[t];
 eq3[t_, q_] := -tn[q]/Gamma[1 - q] Ip1[t, 
     q] + (1 - \[Theta]p) \[Omega]p Ep[t] - (\[Tau]p + \[Mu]p) Ip[t];
 eq4[t_, q_] := -tn[q]/Gamma[1 - q] Ap1[t, q] + \[Theta]p \[Rho]p Ep[
     t] - (\[Tau]ap + \[Mu]p) Ap[t];
 eq5[t_, q_] := -tn[q]/Gamma[1 - q] Rp1[t, q] + \[Tau]p Ip[
     t] + \[Tau]ap Ap[t] - \[Mu]p Rp[t];
 eq6[t_, q_] := -tn[q]/Gamma[1 - q] Mp1[t, q] + \[CurlyRho]p Ip[
     t] + \[CurlyPi]p Ap[t] - \[Pi]p Mp[t];
 eq[q_] := 
  Flatten[Table[{eq1[t, q] == 0, eq2[t, q] == 0, eq3[t, q] == 0, 
     eq4[t, q] == 0, eq5[t, q] == 0, eq6[t, q] == 0}, {t, xcol}]];
 ParallelDo[ (* It is more efficient to parallelize this Do loop *)
  icv[i] = {Sp[0] == 8065518/Np0, Ep[0] == 200000/Np0, 
    Ip[0] == 282/Np0, Ap[0] == 200/Np0, Rp[0] == 0, 
    Mp[0] == 50000/Np0};
  eqM[i] = Join[eq[i], icv[i]];
  solv[i] = 
   FindRoot[eqM[i], Table[{varM[[j]], .1}, {j, Length[varM]}], 
    MaxIterations -> 1000];
  lstSv[i] = 
   Table[{x 120, Np0 Evaluate[Sp[x] /. solv[i]]}, {x, 0, 1, .01}];
  lstEv[i] = 
   Table[{x 120, Np0 Evaluate[Ep[x] /. solv[i]]}, {x, 0, 1, .01}];
  lstIv[i] = 
   Table[{x 120, Np0 Evaluate[Ip[x] /. solv[i]]}, {x, 0, 1, .01}];
  lstAv[i] = 
   Table[{x 120, Np0 Evaluate[Ap[x] /. solv[i]]}, {x, 0, 1, .01}];
  lstRv[i] = 
   Table[{x 120, Np0 Evaluate[Rp[x] /. solv[i]]}, {x, 0, 1, .01}];
  lstMv[i] = 
   Table[{x 120, Np0 Evaluate[Mp[x] /. solv[i]]}, {x, 0, 1, .01}];
  , {i, {99/100, 9/10, 8/10, 7/10, 6/10}}];
 (* Collect the definitions from the parallel kernels to the main \
one, e.g. by: (in principle this should work also by SharedFunction, \
but tat does not work well )*)
 Table[With[{lst = lst}, 
   DownValues[lst] = 
    Flatten@ParallelEvaluate[DownValues[lst]]], {lst, {lstSv, lstEv, 
    lstIv, lstAv, lstRv, lstMv}}];
 ]
```

Comment: Thank you!  Actually I didn't see difference with my code if a piece of code in  `AbsoluteTiming[]` using many times for parameters evaluation.  In this case `ParallelTable[]` running even faster.

Comment: It can be very tricky to optimize parallel evaluations in Mathematica. It also depends on the nature of the problem and also on hardware.

Comment: If memory serves, `WaveletPsi[]` and `WaveletPhi[]` are supposed to produce `Piecewise[]` functions, so if need be, someone could convert the function (by hand?) into something with `Which[]` (or re-express in terms of `UnitStep[]`) so that it could be compileable.

Comment: @RolfMertig You are right, it is a very tricky to optimize code with parallel computation. Any way thank you for your support.

Comment: @J.M. I have used `WaveletPsi[]` and `WaveletPhi[]` with `Compile[]` and it generates `CompiledFunction[]`. What actually wrong with these functions?

Comment: @Alex, that must have been a recent thing (I'm still on version 11); if it is working for you, then my concerns are moot. But just to check: you can use [`CompilePrint[]`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1102) on your functions and check for `MainEvaluate` calls in the output.

Comment: @J.M. I checked it and got `MainEvaluate[ Function[{x}, WaveletPhi[HaarWavelet[], x]][ R0]]` and `MainEvaluate[ Function[{x, k, m}, WaveletPsi[HaarWavelet[], m x - \
k]][ R0, I0, I1]]`.

Comment: Ah, so the compilation did not succeed in that case, @Alex.